# Angular5+ HTTP Get request with HTTP-Basic authentication getting 401 error

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular6, basic-authentication

```
I am trying to access a URL with Basic Authentication.

My URL will return String 

How can I add my username and password to this http request below?
```

** Tried as follows:**

```
headers :any;
 getVersionAPI() {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
       'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password')
      })
    };
   return this.Http.get(this.global.baseURL+this.global.getApiVersion,this.httpOptions).map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }
 getVersion(){
    this.getVersionAPI().subscribe(data => {
      this.apiVersion=data;
    });
  }

Getting 401 error code.
My rest authentication Configuration is as follows:
```

' protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("USER").and()
                    .csrf().disable().headers().frameOptions().disable();
            http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint);
        }'